# Quotient metric on a complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, group-actions

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold on which a Lie group $H$ acts properly and isometrically. Then the induced Riemannian distance function $d:M\times M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a complete, proper $H$-invariant metric (in the sense of metric spaces).

The orbit space $M/H$ is a locally compact space that inherits a length metric $d'$ defined by letting $d'([x],[y])$ be the infimum of $d(w,z)$, where $w$ and $z$ range over elements in the orbits $[x]$ and $[y]$ respectively.

**My question**: is $d'$ a proper metric?

Thoughts: I think this would follow if $d'$ was a complete metric on $M/H$, but I'm not sure if it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Pick an $H$-orbit and look at its closed $R$-neighborhood in $X$. Prove that the $H$-quotient of this neighborhood is compact.

Comment: But we do not assume that $M/H$ is a compact space, so how can a closed $R$-neighbourhood of an $H$-orbit be compact?

Comment: The neighborhood of the orbit is not compact of course, but its quotient is. As an example, take the 1-parameter group of translations of the Euclidean plane. The quotient of the closed R-neighborhood of any orbit will be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: I see. The $H$-quotient of a closed $R$-neighbourhood of an orbit is equal to the image under the projection $M\rightarrow M/H$ of the closed $R$-neighbourhood of any point in the orbit (using that the action is isometric). This image is compact, hence $d'$ is proper. Cheers!

Comment: Right: This kind of a proof is called "follow your nose" (aka "do what's the most obvious thing to try").