# Trying to show triangle inequality with induced distance between orbits.

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group (in all the cases I have seen so far it is compact) and $(X, d)$ a metric space. Suppose that $G$ acts on $X$ and for each $g \in G$, $x \mapsto g \cdot x$ is an isometry and for each $x \in X$, the orbit $o_x$ is closed.

Can I show that $$d^*(o_x, o_y) = \inf_{\substack{a \in o_x \\ b \in o_y}} d(a,b)$$ is a metric on $X/G$?

I showed that the isometry property implies that $d^*(o_x, o_y) = \inf\limits_{g \in G} d(g \cdot x, y)$ and I showed that if the orbits are closed, then $d^*(o_x, o_y) = 0$ implies that $o_x = o_y$. I haven't been able to show the triangle inequality, but I found this question: [Quotient metric on a complete Riemannian manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676085/quotient-metric-on-a-complete-riemannian-manifold)
which made me think it might be possible under some extra assumptions since it seems to be possible in other spaces.

**Edit:** I just saw this question: [Triangle inequality for the distance between two sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480292/triangle-inequality-for-the-distance-between-two-sets)

and realized that
\begin{align*}
d(o_x, z) 
&= \inf\limits_{g \in G} d(g \cdot x, z)\\ 
&= d^*(o_x, o_z)
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
d^*(o_x, o_y) 
&\leq d(o_x, z) + d(z, o_y)\\ 
&= d^*(o_x, o_z) + d^*(o_z, o_y)
\end{align*}
I think that shows it, please correct me if I messed up.

Comment: Fix $z\in X$. For $a\in o_x, b \in o_y$ and $c \in o_z$, then
$d(a,b) \leqslant d(a,c) + d(c,b)$. Hence, $d^{\star}(o_x,o_y) \leqslant d(a,c) + d(b,c)$. To conclude, take the infimum over $a,b$ and $c$.